# Migrate from --deploy-url to base href in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular project that in embedded inside a CMS,  What this means is that the actual files for the app reside in the folder **[www.MyApp.com/Modules/App/dist/](http://www.MyApp.com/Modules/App/dist/)** but the app is served from **[www.MyApp.com/app](http://www.MyApp.com/app)**

I have the build script use `--deploy-url /Modules/App/dist` and I use a small gulp script to update any hard coded assets in the index.html file.

but that is now being depricated.
I tried removing that cli option and updating my angular.json build options to use:

```
"baseHref": "/Modules/App/dist/",
```

as well as adding the following to my providers in app.module

```
 { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'https://www.MyApp.com/app' },
```

as was suggested by [this comment on github](https://%20%7B%20provide:%20APP_BASE_HREF,%20useValue:%20%27https://regent-dev/regent-app%27%20%7D,)

But the app does not load at all with that and if I set the base href to '/' it looks for all the assets and scripts in the [www.MyApp.com/dist](http://www.MyApp.com/dist) folder.

I am also using a **HashLocationStrategy** because the app is not served form the root of the website which ends with **[www.MyApp.com/app#/dashboard](http://www.MyApp.com/app#/dashboard)** where **dashboard** is the root router option

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  /* Lazy Load Modules */
    /* Main route */
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  },
  
   ... all other routes

  /* Default Route - Should be defined right above wildcard route or second last*/
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard/main', pathMatch: 'full' },

];
```

I need help to move away from the deploy-url cli option in our build process.  How should I set the base href options for this.

(Side note, I am open to using a different LocationStrategy if needed)

Comment: dist folder is folder contain files after build production when you config in angular.json and run ng build. If your app served from www.MyApp.com/app, you can use `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app' }` in app.module.ts. After you run ng build complete, you copy all files in dist folder to folder which point to www.MyApp.com/app on server

Comment: @ParkNumb unfortunately that will not be possible. The app is being served by a CMS so the url path and dist folder path cannot be the same because the way the CMS works will not allow it